# How do I detect and possibly change the encryption algorithm used by Vim's "encrypt" mode?

Tags: encryption, vim

I'd like to start using "vim -X" to store encrypted text files. This is a nice introduction on how to do it:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/security/vim-offers-strong-file-encryption-with-blowfish/4870

However, how do I tell for sure what encryption algorithm is being used, and how do a change it to blowfish if it's the older, less secure algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the current encryption method by checking the [`cryptmethod`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#encryption) variable, like so:

```
:set cryptmethod
  cryptmethod=zip
```

Vim only supports `zip` and `blowfish` at the moment, where Blowfish is the stronger method.

Comment: Thanks, that does it. Word of warning, the cryptmethod variable is available in vim7.3 but not 7.2. That's why a couldn't find it. I was on an Ubuntu10.04LTS machine which uses 7.2.

Comment: p.s. I'd upvote you but I don't have the minimum karma to upvote.

Comment: @PeterGroves You can however accept the answer, with the tick mark next to it.